# Unable to get coupon for no.de

Tags: node.js

I tried to get coupons for node smartmachine service through this url

```
curl -u jill:secret https://api.no.de/v1/coupons
```

all i get is this empty set of brackets..

```
[

]
```

how can i get the coupons ?

Comment: have you gotten your coupon yet? I've been waiting and waiting...

Answer (score 3):

That is the command to check what coupons you currently have.

To request a coupon you first need an account, then:

curl -k https://api.no.de/♥ -X POST -u yourusername:yourpassword

Comment: Just to add to this, for me it took around about 10 days to actually get the coupon from the point of submitting the above request